# C: Writing a macro to build string escape sequences

Tags: c, macros, character-encoding, c-preprocessor, c-strings

I'm working with some Japanese C code that prints text in Shift-JIS. In the original code, the text is written directly in kana in string literals. In my editor that expects UTF-8, it shows up as nonsense.

In particular this code likes to use "large" versions of English letters: http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml e.g. \x82\x60 = Ａ (a large "A", \x41 in ASCII). I thought I'd write a CPP macro to convert those from ASCII, like:

```
#define LARGE_LETTER(x) "\x82\x" (x+31)
```

But obviously, this macro doesn't quite work, and I'm not sure how to make it work, if it's even possible. Can you build string escape sequences like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to start off with, why not have a lot of defines

```
#define LARGE_LETTER_A "\x82\x60"
#define LARGE_LETTER_B "\x82\x61"
…
#define LARGE_LETTER_Z "\x82\x7A"
```

Usage

```
char *str = "foo " LARGE_LETTER_A " baz";
```

Next, you can take it up a notch with [primitive cat](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms)

```
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define LARGE_LETTER(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(LARGE_LETTER_, x)
```

Usage:

```
char *str = "foo " LARGE_LETTER(A) " baz";
```

Comment: that's probably the most pragmatic approach, but I don't see any value in the wrapper macro - just use the defines directly; keep in mind that these can be put into a header that gets auto-generated with the scripting language of your choice

Comment: @Christoph `PRIMITIVE_CAT` allows you to combine macros. For example, a macro that returns `A`-`Z` can be combined with `LARGE_LETTER`: `LARGE_LETTER(A_LETTER_SET_ELSEWERE())`. It makes it a bit more flexible.

Comment: The "one define per letter" approach is the kind of repetition I hoped to avoid. I suppose there may not be any alternative?

Comment: I can't make this example work in gcc.