# C Macro to build up a string of string pieces and insert (collate) a byte

Tags: c, string, macros

I would like to have a C macro to build up a string of pieces of strings plus a byte inserted inmidst, like:

`"foo" 0x33 "bar"`

so that the resulting string is `"foo\0x33bar"`.

The variable part of the macro should be the 0x33 in this example.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070063/c-writing-a-macro-to-build-string-escape-sequences) but it doesn't quite match my problem and furthermore it produces an error in gcc when trying to test it out.

EDIT:

```
   void func(const char *);
   char s1[] = { 0x90, 0 };
   char s2[] = { 120,0 };
   func(COLLATE(s1,0x33,s2));

   void func(const char *s) {
       for(int i=0;s[i];i++)
          midi.write(s[i]);
   }
```

such that COLLATE inserts the assembled string there.

EDIT: must correct my example:

func(COLLATE("\0x90",0x33,"\0170"));

Note: The strings may be longer. It's just the point, that one character (0x33) has to be inserted.

Comment: How are you planning to use this macro? A minimal, yet _complete_ example like just `#includes... int main() { puts(THIS_MACRO(...)); }` if that captures what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, usage should be to pass the string as an argument to a function that takes a const char* as an argument.

Comment: What are the actual characters you want in the string? `"foo\0x33bar"` in source code would produce a null character after the “foo”. Do you want f, o, o, null character, x, 3, 3, b, a, r, or f, o, o, backslash, 0, x, 3, 3, bar, or f, o, o, character 51 (hex 33), b, a, r, or something else?

Comment: Edit your post to show code that actually invokes the macro, such as `MyMacro("foo", 0x33, "bar")` and the exact source code that you want to result from that invocation.

Comment: No, I'd like to have 'f','o','o',0x33,'b','a','r',0

Comment: I think there is no way to generate a string literal that contains f, o, o, character 51 (hex 33), b, a, r, null character from macro arguments of `"foo"`, `0x33`, and `"bar"`. C parsing will containing adjacent strings but not strings and integer constants. `0x33` can be made into `\0x33` and `"0x33"`, but you need `"\x33"` to generate character 51 (hex 33), and macro processing will not remove characters like that.

Comment: Some tinkering could be done with compound literals and initializing array members of a structure with strings, but the null terminators will be a problem unless the strings have known sizes.

Comment: The `s1` and `s2` shown in the question currently are not compile-time constants. There is no way a macro could create a string literal from them. Just write a function to concatenate the strings.

Comment: So my example was not well thought. I meant strings I can pass to the macro as compile time constants. Will correct my example accordingly.

Comment: Why do you want such a macro at all? Since all arguments are string literals or constants, can't you simply use adjacent strings? Like `"foo" "\x33" "bar"`? Why do you have the need for integer constants?

Comment: sprintf can do it : sprintf(outstr , ”%s%c%s", str1, theCar, str2)